# C String static buffer byte size

Tags: c

I've been reading the ISO C standard for c strings, and I'm curious as to how the compiler determines the size of the static buffer when a c string is defined? Given the example c string below,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *str = "Jello, World\0";
}
```

The string of 13 characters will be 13 bytes, supposedly; however, according to [§6.5.4 903](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.4.5.html) of the ISO C 07+ standard for string literals,

> 903 The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence.

The "just sufficient," to me, is oddly worded. Does that mean that the static buffer for the c string is not always the exact size needed for a given c string, possibly it may have more space than needed?

I've also found the ISO C 2010 draft and in [§6.5.4 6 pg.71](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf), but this edition also talks about the buffer as "just sufficient." Can someone determine if this buffer is exact or have information for it to be else wise?

Comment: If string is of length `13` bytes then only 13 bytes will be allocated.

Comment: That is 13 characters, not 14?

Comment: There is no static buffer allocated. `str` is a pointer, not an array. And there is no ISO C07 or 2010 standard (drafts are not autoritative). standard is ISO9899:2011, i.e. C11. The previous revision was C99. The standard is very clear about how string literals are converted to a multibyte character sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the string constant `"Jello, World\0"` is `char [14]`.  It's large enough for each character in the string (including any explicit null bytes) plus an implicit null termination byte.

Comment: Thanks, so what you're saying is that the buffer will always be exact? i.e. the string length plus the implicit null character? If that's the case, is their wording in the documentation of using "just sufficient" really just always exact?

Comment: @Miket25 Yes, that's what "just sufficient" means, i.e. big enough to hold the string plus the null byte, but no larger.